# Calculating the probability of several random variables with nonlinear constraints.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

For example, I have three independent random variables $x$,$y$,$z$, all of them are uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$. Now I want to find the probability satisfying the two constraints simultaneously:

$$P\left[\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{\log\left(y\right)}<\frac{4}{3},\frac{\log\left(y\right)}{\log\left(z\right)}<\frac{3}{2}\right]$$
I know the basic method to find the volume by integration manually, and I can obtain the answer $4/15$. However it is too complicated and  I could have more of these variables and more constraints.

My question is, for such problem, is there a systematic way or formula to obtain the probability  directly? Or, can these be transformed into exponential distributions and simplify the calculation?

Comment: Are the random variables independent?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes

Comment: Then, **edit** your question to include this information in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The answer is given by:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{{\ln\pars{x} \over \ln\pars{y}} < {4 \over 3}}
\bracks{{\ln\pars{y} \over \ln\pars{z}} < {3 \over 2}}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{x > y^{4/3}}\bracks{z < y^{2/3}}\dd x\,\dd z\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y^{\large{2/3}}}\int_{y^{\large{4/3}}}^{1}
\dd x\,\dd z\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}y^{2/3}\pars{1 - y^{4/3}}\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{y^{2/3} - y^{2}}\,\dd y =
\left.\pars{{y^{5/3} \over 5/3} - {y^{3} \over 3}}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 1} =
{3 \over 5} - {1 \over 3} = \bbx{4 \over 15}
\end{align}